# GTK File Chooser: How to disable automatic search after folder selection?

Tags: gtk, file-search, file-chooser

When I open the GTK File Chooser Dialog to save a file and I start typing, the text goes into the filename text field (as expected). Now when I first choose a directory and then start typing, the text goes into a search box field, *although the filename is still highlighted* (see Screenshot). How can I disable this automatic search box focusing? I would be fine with disabling the search completely as well.

[Screenshot of Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4CHr.png)

I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1033414/how-to-disable-gtkfilechooserdialog-search) which actually refers to the typeahead feature, and [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1316211/how-to-completely-disable-quick-search-in-gtk) which sadly has no answer.

Comment: I've found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/387957) with no recent activity. Seems like this is an issue for many users

Comment: A workaround mentioned there is to use `ALT + N` to set the focus on the filename field